# Redis Exceptions : from High CPU or Redis exceptions causing High CPU

Tags: redis

I am trying to debug the reason for these errors raised on Sitecore 8.2u5 on Azure PaaS , Redis Plan C1. We had already have deployed Sitecore patch Sitecore.Support.210408.config , in which the MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU, MinWorkerThreadsPerCore,MinCompletionPortThreadsPerCore were tweaked

There are a couple of other variations of the Redis exceptions as well.
Any help appreciated to understand if Redis exceptions are being caused due to High CPU or vice versa

```
7132 14:21:25 ERROR GetItemFromSessionStore => StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 11, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 29, qu: 0, qs: 29, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 39618, ar: 0, clientName: RD00, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/orgname-prod-fs-sitecore-blue-450270-redis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, keyHashSlot: 10876, IOCP: (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=70,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=27,Free=32740,Min=250,Max=32767) (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[] keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Eval>b__0()
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryForScriptNotFound(Func`1 redisOperation)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryLogic(Func`1 redisOperation)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.Eval(String script, String[] keyArgs, Object[] valueArgs)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.TryTakeWriteLockAndGetData(String sessionId, DateTime lockTime, Object& lockId, ISessionStateItemCollection& data, Int32& sessionTimeout)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.GetItemFromSessionStore(Boolean isWriteLockRequired, Http
   --------------------
   
7132 14:21:25 ERROR Cannot create tracker.
Exception: StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException
Message: Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 11, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 29, qu: 0, qs: 29, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 39618, ar: 0, clientName: RD0, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/orgname-prod-fs-sitecore-blue-450270-redis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, keyHashSlot: 10876, IOCP: (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=70,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=27,Free=32740,Min=250,Max=32767) (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
Source: StackExchange.Redis.StrongName
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[] keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Eval>b__0()
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryForScriptNotFound(Func`1 redisOperation)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryLogic(Func`1 redisOperation)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.Eval(String script, String[] keyArgs, Object[] valueArgs)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.TryTakeWriteLockAndGetData(String sessionId, DateTime lockTime, Object& lockId, ISessionStateItemCollection& data, Int32& sessionTimeout)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.GetItemFromSessionStore(Boolean isWriteLockRequired, HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actions)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actions)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.SharedSessionState.SharedSessionStateManager.LockAndLoadContact(Guid contactId)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.TryLoadContact(Guid contactId, Int32 lockDurationMinutes, Boolean exclusive)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.LoadContact.Process(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureSessionContextPipeline.Run(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.EnsureSessionContext()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateTracker.GetTracker.Process(CreateTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Initialize()
```

Comment: There are many blogs on this topic. What have you tried? If you haven’t tried the compression change please do: https://sitecorerap.wordpress.com/2021/01/22/you-should-probably-enable-compression-if-youre-having-redis-timeout-issues/

Comment: We have tried the compression , polling intervals, maxrequests. Raised requests with sitecore support they are saying High CPU could be due to insufficient cache and SQL roundtrips and which in turn is causing Redis timeouts.

Comment: Got it, then they are correct.  In my extensive experience dealing with this, the issue is likely not Redis-related. However, due to its high use of threads, it is often the first piece of code to indicate another issue. The best technique now is to take memory dumps when the application is experiencing problems. I can tell you from experience that after applying all of the Redis best-practices (compression being the biggest factor) all Redis-related problems disappeared. And any time we saw a Timeout like yours, it was due to a different system clogging the pipe.

Comment: Actually their assumption was based on Un-tuned caches , which is not true now , since we already tuned the caches. 
Further discussion with Sitecore has yielded that the Large amount of SharedSession object could mean that Sitecore is unable to process Expired sessions